# What's the relation between WinAPI and .NET?

Tags: .net, winapi

I'm a C# developer, and I'm trying to grasp what's the role of WinAPI on Windows development. My perception is that it is the sole exposition of the kernel itself, and that, before .NET, it was also the "Windows development" itself (not counting non-Microsoft technologies), but I'm not sure of none of these statements. Also, I am unsure of what is the relation of WinAPI and the .NET framework. So I got a few questions:

- Is the entire .NET runtime built on top of WinAPI? If so, is WinAPI really the lowest-level interface for developing on Windows?
- What is the role of each on Windows development (in any area, like web, business, software products, etc) nowadays?
- Are there more WinAPI (C/C++) developers than .NET developers nowadays?
- Where do WinRT enters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Windows API is (more or less) the substrate that underlies .NET, yes.

No, it is not the lowest level of development for Windows. Windows NT was originally intended to be a sort-of Microkernel, with Win32 as only one of several possible subsystems running on it. These subsystems use the Windows NT "native API" to talk to the microkernel. It's possible to write other code to use the native API directly as well.

The next step "below" that would probably be device driver code, but it's enough different that it's open to question whether it really counts. You don't normally use it to write applications at all, but (obviously enough) device drivers.

WinRT is basically a new API that sits (more or less) alongside the existing Windows API, and provides services via a COM interface.

I won't try to cover roles and/or number of developers. Determining roles is largely subjective, and I doubt anybody really knows the exact number of developers doing specific kinds of work.

Comment: Agree. Winapi can be used for all applications, .net is for end-user applications with lower requirements to speed and resource consumption.

Comment: It should be added that Win32 still has a privileged position as a subsystem, compared to any other available subsystems (including what used to be Interix and is now available for free). For example only the Win32 subsystem appears to be able to use all graphics hardware. Still +1, nice summary.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation on resources about the NT architecture? What about the implementation of .NET? (That "more or less" gave me an urge to know the whole.)

Comment: @Raphael: Be prepared to spend some time if you want to know it in detail. David Solomon's books are a good starting point for architecture. I don't know of many good books about .NET internals -- you mostly have to scavenge bits and pieces from web sites, blogs, etc. If you're willing to sift through a lot to find it, MSDN has quite a bit, but much of it is almost hidden in documentation about basics of how to use it, deploy apps, etc.

Comment: Thanks, @JerryCoffin. I'll take a look at the books (at least as much as I can endure) and have a research on .NET. It's weird that this is so undocumented.

Answer (score 3):

The WinAPI is a layer on top of the native Windows api, one that isn't documented.  There used to be two other api layers, Posix and OS/2 but they fell out of use.  The .NET framework is an api layer as well.  On Windows, it indeed uses the winapi layer for core OS services.  But that's not exclusive, Mono for example can run on top of Linux and OSX.

For native user mode Windows development, the WinAPI is indeed the core api layer you'd use.  There are certainly still plenty of programmers that use it.  But most programmers use .NET, Java or a web hosted language like Javascript or PHP.

WinRT is a *replacement* for the WinAPI.  It is COM based, rather than the C-based interface of WinAPI.  Little of that is visible in the development tools, their respective runtimes have a "projection" of the WinRT so you don't have to write COM code directly.  And so you can still write C# code.  Just with different base classes.